# Cannot disable angular cli warning

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I cannot disable this warning in Visual studio code

> Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.7) is greater than your local
>   version (1.7.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch
>   false"

whenever I type this "ng config", it returns this error

> The specified command config is invalid. For available options, see
>   `ng help`.

please help thanks.

Comment: type ```ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false``` in command line.

Comment: May I ask, why you want to disable the warning?

Comment: well, it shows up every time I do something on angular CLI in which it takes up a lot of space. @schlonzo

Comment: Ah OK, I understand

Comment: @fatemefazli it not working. see this sc https://www.screencast.com/t/EgPUINoPK

Comment: either downgrade your global CLI or upgrade your local CLI

Comment: ```npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest``` ,it will update your local cli version.

Answer (score -1):

First update your local angular version using following command.

```
npm update
```

then it will start working.
if it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: What of his package.json requirement setting

Comment: this cannot be a valid answer. The reason he is seeing the error message that he wants to disable is because the local cli version is too old. Updating the entire project to the new version seems like the long way around the problem of "disable an optional warning message"